# Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises

Tags: discord.js

It is not written that this module is needed in any of the codes
I tried to download this module but it did not work
please help me

````
Require stack:
- C:\Users\danie\Desktop\DiscordBot-Template-master\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.js
- C:\Users\danie\Desktop\DiscordBot-Template-master\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\lib\RequestManager.js
- C:\Users\danie\Desktop\DiscordBot-Template-master\node_modules\@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js
- C:\Users\danie\Desktop\DiscordBot-Template-master\bot.js
←[90m    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:730:27)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)←[39m
←[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:88:18)←[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\danie\Desktop\DiscordBot-Template-master\node_modules\←[4m@discordjs←[24m\rest\dist\lib\handlers\SequentialHandler.js:6:20)
←[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1068:30)←[39m
←[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:10)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:933:32)←[39m
←[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:14)←[39m
←[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:19)←[39m {
  code: ←[32m'MODULE_NOT_FOUND'←[39m,
  requireStack: [
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\DiscordBot-Template-master\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\rest\\dist\\lib\\handlers\\SequentialHandler.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\DiscordBot-Template-master\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\rest\\dist\\lib\\RequestManager.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\DiscordBot-Template-master\\node_modules\\@discordjs\\rest\\dist\\index.js'←[39m,
    ←[32m'C:\\Users\\danie\\Desktop\\DiscordBot-Template-master\\bot.js'←[39m
  ]
}```
````

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is most probably due to incompatible node version, consider downloading [node.js v16 and above](https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/) if it is already at v16 consider updating your types by running the following in the shell.

```sh
npm install --save-dev @types/node@latest
```

Answer (score 17):

This issue can be solved by simple updating your node environment to `node 16.x`

The easiest way of doing this is by using [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)

```
nvm install 16
nvm use 16
```