# DiscordJS module fail

Tags: javascript, reactjs, discord

I am working with DiscordJS, NodeJS 16. I am creating a method that sends a message to Discord using a Webhook. The problem is that when compiling I get the following error:

```
error - ./node_modules/@discordjs/rest/dist/index.js:282:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'timers/promises'

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/discord.js/src/index.js
./services/discord/sendDiscordMessage.ts
./services/discord/index.ts
./components/FormSubdivision/index.tsx
./components/RookieComponents/RookieConfigSections/FirstSection.tsx
./components/RookieComponents/RookieConfigSections/index.ts
./components/RookieComponents/index.ts
./pages/rookie/config/index.tsx
```

This is the function:

```
import { AuthContext } from "context";
import { useContext } from "react";

const { EmbedBuilder, WebhookClient } = require('discord.js');

const webhookClient = new WebhookClient({
  url: ...,
});

const sendDiscordMessage = (message: string) => {
  const { user }: any = useContext(AuthContext)

  const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
    .setDescription(message)
    .setColor("#fff");

  webhookClient.send({
    content: "",
    username: user.username,
    avatarURL: "",
    embeds: [embed],
  });
}

export default sendDiscordMessage
```

Following the trace, the error occurs in node_modules, in the @discordjs module, in the following line:

```
var import_promises = require("timers/promises");
```

Any idea what this error could be?

**UPDATE 21/10**

I have found the solution. DiscordJS does not work from a browser, that is, the request to the Discord API must be made from the backend, and not from the frontend

Comment: If you are using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timers-promises) module, then it's `timers-promises`, not `timers/promises`

Comment: I am not using any module apart from discordjs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69062820/error-cannot-find-module-timers-promises)

Comment: I've edited the question with the solution I found, thanks!